# How to display each attachment's ID on individual attachment details pages in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display ID numbers of my WordPress attachments on individual attachment details pages. My current code can display attachment ID but I can't figure out how to make a working loop in order to get every ID to be displayed on its own attachment details pages. Now there is only one ID number on every attachment page, the same one.

I've tried with WP_query, query_posts, get_posts. No luck. This is my code which is only partially working (because of lacking loop part) and it is placed in my functions.php file.

```
function id_on_attachment_pages() {

    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ($attachments as $post) {
            $id = var_dump($post->ID);
        }
    }

    $attachment_id[] = array(
        "label" => "$id",
    );
    return $attachment_id;
}

add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "id_on_attachment_pages");
```

EDIT: It might be a little bit confusing so let me clarify something, I'm talking about "attachment **details**" page, not about attachment page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the global variable of wordpress, you dont need to make a request to get the id you need. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

```
global $post; 
var_dump($post);
```

Dont forget to escape the html if needed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I was trying to include global variable and var_dump in my code, with WP_Query loops and with no loops, still not working. I've edited my original code, you meant something like that? Now I get endless loop while media library is loading attachments.